# Calling a dart method in another dart file from main.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call a dart method which is in another dart file from main. dart. For some reason the method seems to inaccessible. Here I am trying to access the _configureAmplify method which is in another class. I got all the import added correctly. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my main.dart class -

```
class _AmplifyFlutterState extends State<AmplifyFlutter> {
  bool _amplifyConfigured = false;


  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Authentication._configureAmplify().then((result) {
      if (result) {
        setState(() {
          _amplifyConfigured = true;
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUpScreen()));
        });
      } else {
        _amplifyConfigured = false;
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Here is the other class which defines the _configureAmplify method

```
class Authentication {
    
      Future<bool> _configureAmplify() async {
        bool _amplifyConfigured = false;
        Amplify.addPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito());
        try {
          await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
        }
        on AmplifyAlreadyConfiguredException {
          print("Amplify was already configured. Was the app restarted?");
        } catch(e) {
          print(e);
        }
        return _amplifyConfigured;
      }
    }
```

EDIT
[image]

Comment: Remove the underscore from _configureAmplify .. as the underscore are use to make it private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart, when you proceed a function with `_` it makes it private ie. inaccessible from outside the class.

If the function is only meant to be used from within the class, it's always better to keep it private. But if you need to access it from outside, then it needs to be public with no underscore.

Comment: Still when I do Authentication with a dot in main.dart file the intellisense doesn't give me the option to choose configureAmplify. When i punch it in manually I get a red squiggly under the method name.

Comment: I have edited the original post with a pic

Comment: Either add `()` after Authentication or create an `Authentication` object `final authentication = Authentication();` then use `authentication.configureAmplify();`

Comment: newbie to flutter and dart. thanks Loren.A